# Adding a div inside a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

css:

```css
#space{
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background:blue;
    }
#button{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    background:red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#box{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: white;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="space"></div>
<div id="button"></div>
```

javascript:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#space").append($('#box'));
});
```

I tried to add the div "box" to the div "space" on each click over the div "button".But the code is not working.Can anyone say what is the error on it ?

Comment: Do you need to create DIV?

Comment: where's the #box div?

Comment: That's the point,the div #box was actually missing ! My bad :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, but right now Javascript doesn't know what `#box` is. To add a `<div>` to a `<div>` on a button press, do this (and you're close):

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  $("#space").append('<div></div>');
});
```

Something to keep in mind, `id`'s need to be unique, so try using a class instead, and adjusting your CSS to target the class:

```
// Javascript
$("#button").click(function(){
  $("#space").append('<div class="box"></div>');
});

// CSS
.box{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: white;
}
```

Hope that helps!

**Edit**

Just an interesting observation using OP's base code with a `#box` present:

```
// Before Click
<div id="space">Space</div>
<div id="box">Box</div>
<div id="button">Button</div>

// After Click
<div id="space">Space
  <div id="box">Box</div>
</div>
<div id="button">Button</div>
```

It works in that it moves the `#box` inside the `#space`, and doesn't create a new `#box` object. So it's not adding so much as moving.

Comment: Also probably a little more cleaner to simply `append('<div class="box"></div>')`.

Comment: is there a reason for the $ inside the append? (just curious)

Comment: @dfsq and Tim Lewis - it's an `id` not a `class`

Comment: yeah ! my bad :( ,i was hooked on it for hours ! thank you :) @TimLewis

Comment: @jmore009 Read my whole answer... I said don't use an id, as if you press it more than once, you have an HTML violation with non-unique ids.

Answer (score 3):

when using `$('#box')` you're telling jQuery to look for an element with `id='box'` in your DOM, if it dosen't exsist, you will not append anything.

Do you have a #box element on your site?
otherwise you could try this:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  $("#space").append('<div id="box"></div>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to appending an `id` that does not exist on the page when it loads. You need to create the div with an `id` of "box":

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  $("#space").append('<div id="box"></div>');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2pst1par/)